# Ansible syncronize command for rsync for copying large backups from remote to local

Tags: ansible, rsync

Ansible fetch does not work - getting a "shared connection closed" with large backup files (same command for small files works). A post on stackoverflow says its probably the Raspberry Pi that runs out of available memory to process - I do not want to load addt. ram drives. (Env - local = Mac, remote = Raspberry Pi).

So, trying ansible.posix.synchronize command - problem is - I am using an odd ssh port, so I do not know how to set the port, and ssh.

The following normal rsync command on local host, pulling the backup from remote, does work:

```
rsync -z -e "ssh -p 2389"  user@host1.lan:/tmp/ghostbackups/ $HOME/backup_directory
```

I tried the following Ansible command:

```
ansible.posix.synchronize:
  mode: pull
  src: user@host1.lan:/tmp/ghostbackups/
  dest: $HOME/backup_directory
  compress: yes
  rsync_opts:
   -  "-e ssh -p 2389"
```

Is it possible to use synchronize to achieve same as the working rsync command?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working - correct command does not require the remote host - Ansible handles that. Following works.

```
ansible.posix.synchronize:
  mode: pull
  src: /tmp/ghostbackups/
  dest: $HOME/backup_directory
  compress: yes
  rsync_opts:
   -  "-e ssh -p 2389"
```